# Reference one project from another one

Tags: c#, join

As a final project our team has created a system using c#. Our system has two major parts. 
1.login system
2.The main dashboard with other sub systems.

So my problem is this project was created by a team.
ex: "Login system" and "main dashboard with sub systems" is designed by two different persons, means those two are created as two different projects using c#..and each system also works perfectly

So I need to  join those two parts together.. ex: When I logging in by the user credentials, then it would open the main dashboard.. I tried combining those two projects by using "Add existing project" in  the login system, but it doesn't show the name of the "dashboard" ex:

```
this.close();
dashboard db = new dashboard();
db.Showdialog();
```

The name "dashboard won't show up".. So how to combine those seperate projects together?

Comment: @SahanJawardena what you did is not enough, you need to add the one project as reference to another project. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: You should differentiate between a solution to which you can add projects, and an actual project whcih compiles to an assembly (e.g. a .dll) and that can *reference* other assemblies. So in your case you need the login-project to reference the dashborad-project. Furthermore you have to add a `using`-directive for the namespace where `dashborad` is defined in.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand it properly.. I added the dashboard project file using add reference.. But the problem doesn't solved..

Answer (score 3):

Adding another project to the solution merely allows you to easily edit all projects simultaneously; it doesn't connect the projects in any way. You can [add a project-to-project reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to refer to classes in one project from another (the referenced project's output assembly will be copied to the build directory).

Comment: He might also need to import the  namespace which contains `dashboard` class after referencing the project. Without importing the appropriate namespace compiler will give errors.